# htaccess not reading php file

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I seem to be lost in a big pile of code. I have the following piece of .htaccess code:

```
RewriteRule ^user/(.*)$ index.php?p=user/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^user/(.*)/(.*)$ index.php?p=user/$1&id=$2 [L]
```

Now, I have a file called profile.php, inside that I use $_GET to get the ID. But when I go to /user/profile/1, it does nothing. When I go there without a ID, my script works. Can somebody help me out and tell me what I am doing wrong?

Thank you. Sorry for the confusing message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try these 2 rules:

```
RewriteRule ^user/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ index.php?p=user/$1&id=$2 [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^user/([^/]+)/?$ index.php?p=user/$1 [L,QSA]
```

**Explanation:**

Reason why your rule aren't working because your regex is wrong. You first rule `^user/(.*)$` has `.*` which is matching **everything** after `/user/` hence your 2nd rule never fires and `$_GET['id']` is always empty.

By changing that to `[^/]+` my rule is matching only until next `/` is found hence both rules co-exist fine.

`QSA` is just nice flag to have here to preserve any existing query string.

Comment: Maybe I am rude, but this works and I like to know what I did wrong. What is QSA? and what is the [^/]+ difference from .*. Thanks.

Comment: No you aren't rude at all. It is fair to ask for the reasons. Let me add explanation to my answer.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation! I will keep in mind to do some research in the future before asking stupid questions. Thanks again.

Comment: You're welcome, and it not stupid at all. You rules would also have worked by reversing the order.